# How can a Trailblazer Operation with Paperdragon process an image sequentially?

Tags: trailblazer

In a Trailblazer operation that uses Paperdragon to process an image, code like this is typical:

```
def process(params)
  validate(params) do |f| 
    f.image!(f.upload) do |v| 
      v.process!(:original)
      v.process!(:version_a) { |job| job.something... }
      v.process!(:version_b) { |job| job.something... }
      v.process!(:version_c) { |job| job.something... }
      end 
    end 
  end 
end
```

which would create four versions from an uploaded image that is accessible as `upload` on the operation's contract.

I would like to do a few things to `:original` resulting in `:edited` and then use `:edited` as the baseline for `:verson_a`, `:version_b` and `:version_c`. How can I achieve that with Paperdragon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a second processing block using a version created by the first as its input:

```
def process(params)
  validate(params) do |f| 
    f.image!(f.upload) do |v| 
      v.process!(:original)
      v.process!(:edited) { |job| job.thumb!(crop) }
      end 
    end 
    f.image!(f.file(:edited)) do |v| 
      v.process!(:version_a) { |job| job.something... }
      v.process!(:version_b) { |job| job.something... }
      v.process!(:version_c) { |job| job.something... }
    end                                                                           
    f.save
  end 
end
```

where `file` is a method on the contract:

```
def file(version)
  File.new(Dragonfly.app.datastore.server_root+image[version.to_sym].url)
end
```